# Windows 7 standard user with time limit but install/run admin rights, like in the old LAN Caffe's

Tags: windows-7, installation, uac, privileges

How can i limit the time spent on a computer for a standard/administrator but also give him the possibility to install software without the UAC prompt?

Context:
I'm trying to limit the time my brother spends on the computer as a request from our parents, but i want to allow him to install whatever he wants on it. Is this possible? I was thinking that old LAN Caffe's had this. When you would buy X h time on a PC you could do anything within that time limit. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict administrative user time natively, coffee shops will use a tool for restricting time.

You limit standard user time with the Family settings.

Put the computer in a shared area of the home so that it can be monitored with the Mk 1 eyeball.